# Quick question about the relation between elementary classes and pseudo-elementary classes

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a logic and $\mathscr{K}$ a class of structures in the vocabulary of $\mathcal{L}$. We say that $\mathscr{K}$ is a (basic) elementary class iff there is $\phi \in \mathcal{L}$ such that $\mathscr{K} = \{\mathfrak{A} \; | \; \mathfrak{A} \models \phi\}$. $\mathscr{K}$ is a pseudo-elementary class (or, alternatively, a projective class) iff there is an elementary class $\mathscr{K}'$ in a vocabulary $\tau' \supseteq \tau$ (where $\tau$ is the vocabulary of $\mathscr{K}$) such that $\mathscr{K} = \{\mathfrak{A}\restriction \tau \; | \; \mathfrak{A} \in \mathscr{K}'\}$. Finally, a class $\mathscr{K}$ is a relativized pseudo-elementary class iff there is $\tau' \supseteq \tau$, a unary relation symbol $U \in \tau' \setminus \tau$, and an elementary class $\mathscr{K}'$ of vocabulary $\tau'$ such that $\mathscr{K} = \{(\mathfrak{A} \restriction \tau)\mid U^\mathfrak{A} \; | \; \mathfrak{A} \in \mathscr{K}' \text{ and } U^\mathfrak{A} \text{ is } \tau\text{-closed in } \mathfrak{A}\}$. $(\mathfrak{A} \restriction \tau)\mid U^\mathfrak{A}$ is the relativized reduct of $\mathfrak{A}$ (basically, you consider only the domain "U" of $\mathfrak{A}$).

My question is rather simple: what are the inclusion relations between these classes? It seems to me that $\mathrm{EC}_\mathcal{L} \subseteq \mathrm{PC}_\mathcal{L} \subseteq \mathrm{RPC}_\mathcal{L}$. My reasoning is that we can always restrict the vocabulary of the structures in a $\mathrm{EC}_\mathcal{L}$ class to the basic vocabulary of the $\phi$ in question, and that, if the logic allows sentences such as $\forall x Ux$, then every $\mathrm{PC}_\mathcal{L}$ can be made into a $\mathrm{RPC}_\mathcal{L}$ class; is this correct?

EDIT: Added a more explicit definition of relativized pseudo-elementary class.

Comment: Can you possibly explain a little bit more what relativized pseudo-elementary class is? (The first inclusion seems obvious, since one can consider elementary class as a pseudo-elementary class "with respect to itself", so I am assuming you are concerned with the second inclusion, right?)

Comment: @PavelC - I added a clarification. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you.I think I now understand your idea and think that it works, but maybe backwards: You have a pseudo-el. class $\mathscr{K}$, hence an el. class $\mathscr{K}'$ in language $\tau'$ from which it comes and then you add the new $U$ to the language, interpret it in $\mathscr{K}'$ as $U^\mathfrak{A}=\mathfrak{A}, \; \mathfrak{A} \in \mathscr{K}'$ to obtain $\mathscr{K}''=\{\mathfrak{A} \; | \; \mathfrak{A} \models \phi \wedge (\forall x)(U{x})\}$, i.e. still elementary which gives you, after forgetting the symbols $\tau'\setminus \tau$ the psudo-el. class $\mathscr{K}'''$ and relativize it.

Comment: @PavelC - Thanks, I think that makes sense. Since the relativization of $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{A}$ is just $\mathfrak{A}$, the relativized class is just the pseudo-elementary class, right?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant (I just ran out of symbols : ) ).